# How do I create a view with mixed languages, showing the node's original language by default?

Tags: 7, views, i18n-l10n

I have a site with mixed languages, Spanish and English. Some content was originally created in English, then translated into Spanish. Other content was originally created in Spanish, then translated into English. The remaining content is either in Spanish or English and is not translated.

How do I create a view that shows all of this content in the original content (non-translated) language, showing a view with a mix of English and Spanish? Then if the user chooses English or Spanish, it will show only those languages.

[image: The Original Content Language]

Comment: Site is Drupal 7.72

Answer (score 0):

To show only the "original" nodes in any language don't include any language filters so all languages are shown. This will show all your content, translated or not in both languages.

It's not clear from your question what you mean by "that shows all of this content".

If you want to show only the nodes that were originals, and not a translation of another, add the `Source translation` Filter from the `Content translation` Category. Set it to `Include untranslated content: Yes` if you want only the nodes that haven't been translated yet.

Set it to `No` if you only want to show nodes that already have a translation node.

I'm guessing you'll want the **No** selected, or you won't need the Content translation Filter filter at all.

Then add the `Content: Language` Filter and Expose it to allow visitors to filter the language. Select only the two specific language options and the `Limit list to selected items` if you only want those to be the options your visitors see and are able to choose (so they don't see options like "Site default", "Current", etc).